# Linkedin oauth2 api, authorization do not return "state"

Tags: oauth-2.0, state, linkedin-api

I'm passing `state=;xyz` in authorization request. I can see the same in url on browser on Allow screen. After clicking "Allow" button, i get access token i.e. code with the redirect uri, but Linkedin does not return `state` in the redirect_uri.

Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it just by doing trial and error. The error was silly on my end.
I was passing `state=;xyz` but linkedin expects `state=%3Bxyz`.
Linkedin just ignores `;` and following characters and since i did not have anything before `;`, linkedin was considering it as empty value and was not returning state. Silly on my end.
[@starlight54](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4214709/starlight54) thanks for spending some time for me.

Answer (score 2):

The `state` parameter is either not required or MUST be present in responses according to the grant and part of flow in question. I have to go out on a limb and say that LinkedIn haven't written a spec violating OAuth 2.0 implementation, so perhaps you are using/expecting `state` when you shouldn't be or are using it in the right place but incorrectly?

1. Authorization Code Grant (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1) `state` will not be in the `access_token` response, only in the Authorization `code` response if you sent one with the request for the `code`.
2. Implicit Grant (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2) `state` will be returned with the `access_token` if you sent one in your token request.
3. Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3) `state` is not used at all.
4. Client Credentials Grant (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4) `state` is not used at all.

If you find LinkedIn are in violation of the spec, then it'd be worth letting them know!